# Angular ng build replacing & with &amp;

Tags: angular, build

Using both Angular 15 and 16 I just noticed a problem with the output of 'ng build' rewriting a URL in the index.html page that it generates.

My orignal index.html contains the following line

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

The builder output modifies it to this:

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there a setting in the builder to prevent this, or is this a bug?